# Word VBA macro button only works once

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a button that copies the contents of an entire page, and pastes it to a new page within the same document. When I first formatted this as a MacroButton (CTRL + F9) it would work multiple times. Now I have tried it using a command button under Legacy forms (Developer tab) as a click event, and it will only work once. I am not sure why this is occuring. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub AddPage3_Click()
 Const wdPageBreak = 7
 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Range.Copy
 Selection.InsertBreak (wdPageBreak)
 Selection.Paste
 Selection.TypeBackspace
 Selection.TypeBackspace
End Sub
```

When I press the button, it will create another page in the document with the contents of the active page (the page the button is located on), but it will not work a second time. If you have any suggestions please let me know :)!

Comment: Because you copy paste your button as well and this action renames your button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After copy/paste, you can rename your commandbutton as follows and the commandbutton keeps running each time:

```
Private Sub AddPage3_Click()
Dim shp As InlineShape
Const wdPageBreak = 7
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Range.Copy
Selection.InsertBreak (wdPageBreak)
Selection.Paste
Selection.TypeBackspace
Selection.TypeBackspace
For Each shp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    On Error Resume Next
    If shp.OLEFormat.ClassType = "Forms.CommandButton.1" Then
        If shp.OLEFormat.Object.Name = "AddPage31" Then
            shp.OLEFormat.Object.Name = "AddPage3"
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work except that I am getting a run-time error '91' object variable or with block variable not set. Why is this occuring?

Comment: At which line do you get this? Try putting `On Error Resume Next` before the error line and see if your code still work as intended.

Comment: I believe it was the first if statement line. Adding the On Error line now lets the code complete without an error at the end, so I believe it worked. Thanks!